How to open a 'save webpage' with all the photos on iPhone?
My intention is to download a particular Facebook page and read it offline. As described in this site, I did Ctrl + S and have now a folder and .html file saved on my PC. Now, how do I open this webpage offline on iPhone. I'm fine with any browser.
